# Why does R power.prop.test & R prop.test show inconsistent results?

Tags: r, experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test

I am a bit confused by the differences I am seeing between R's power.prop.test & prop.test functions.

To estimate the sample size needed for an A/B test I am conducting I am using the following function:

```
> power.prop.test(n=NULL, p1=.01, p2=.02, sig.level=.05, power=.8, alternative='two.sided')

 Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

          n = 2318.165
         p1 = 0.01
         p2 = 0.02
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

The way I am interpreting this is that in order to detect a change of at least 1% absolute, I would need **at least** 2318 samples in each group.

Now when I use the prop.test function below, I see a discrepency.

```
> prop.test(x=c(20, 40), n=c(2000, 2000), correct=FALSE, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  c(20, 40) out of c(2000, 2000)
X-squared = 6.7682, df = 1, p-value = 0.00928
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.017527385 -0.002472615
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.01   0.02
```

Here it seems that with **only 2000** observations in each bucket a significant 1% change has been detected at the 95% confidence level. This seems to directly contradict the power.prop.test results that said at least 2318 observations were needed to detect a change of that size.

Why is this discrepancy happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example ignores power considerations. For doing so, you would need to draw many samples from the hypothezised distributions, not just one.

If we simulate 10'000 samples with only $n_1 = 2000$, then we find signficant results only in 75% of all cases at a level of 5%. With $n_1 = 2318$, we reach the expected 80%.

```
################################
# Example with only n1 = 2000
################################
n1 <- 2000
B <- 10000
pvalues <- numeric(B)

set.seed(3)
x1 <- rbinom(B, n1, 0.01)
x2 <- rbinom(B, n1, 0.02)

for (i in seq_len(B)) {
 pvalues[i] <- prop.test(x=c(x1[i], x2[i]), n=c(n1, n1), correct=FALSE, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)$p.value
}

# Power
mean(pvalues <= 0.05) # 0.7449

################################
# Example with n1 = 2318
################################

n1 <- 2318
B <- 10000
pvalues <- numeric(B)

set.seed(3)
x1 <- rbinom(B, n1, 0.01)
x2 <- rbinom(B, n1, 0.02)

for (i in seq_len(B)) {
 pvalues[i] <- prop.test(x=c(x1[i], x2[i]), n=c(n1, n1), correct=FALSE, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)$p.value
}

# Power
mean(pvalues <= 0.05) # 0.8091
```

NOTE ABOUT THE CODE: This example uses purposely an old school for-loop instead of `apply` to increase readability.